# Как указать сразу несколько прав discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в разрешениях стояли ban_members и view_audit_log, но если у пользователя есть права на ban_members, но нет права на view_audit_log, то функция не срабатывает.

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду. Если функция требует наличия обоих прав, то у вас должны быть включены и `ban_members` и `view_audit_log`. По крайней мере, пока вы не предоставите код самой функции, понять что не так не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то используйте следующую схему:

```
@client.command()

@commands.has_permissions({permission1} = True, {permission2} = True)
#дальше код команды
```

Заменяете {permission} на нужное вам право.